# AVPlayerLayer not sizing correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that displays either an image or a video. If there's a video, it initially downloads and displays the thumbnail from that video while the video is loading and preparing to play.

It all works, the problem is that I get the ratio of the thumbnail, store it in the database and when I download the thumbnail, it makes the height based on that ratio. It works great for images. But the issue is that the `AVPlayerLayer` frame doesn't cover the entire thumbnail and it looks like this:

[image]

Here's how I do it:

```
 func updateView() {

    if let videoUrlString = post?.videoUrl, let videoUrl = URL(string: videoUrlString) {
        volumeView.isHidden = false
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer!.frame = postImageView.frame // thumbnail image
        playerLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
        self.volumeView.layer.zPosition = 1
        layoutIfNeeded()
        player?.play()
        player?.isMuted = videoIsMuted
    }

    if let ratio = post?.ratio {
        photoHeightConstraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / ratio
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
 }
```

I'm not doing something right apparently or I'm missing something based on my final result. Any clue?

**UPDATE:**
I notice that if you scroll the cells slowly, the video is being displayed according to the size of the thumbnail. But if you scroll fast, it mismatches the frame. I assume it has something to do with reusability or it simply cannot catch up with the frame? Here's my code for `prepareForReuse()` method:

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
    postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "profile_placeholder")
    volumeView.isHidden = true
    if let p = player, let pLayer = playerLayer {
        p.pause()
        pLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

Comment: try 
playerLayer!.frame = contentView.bounds instead of  playerLayer!.frame = postImageView.frame. And for the love of god, apply optional chaining, it will look better :)

Comment: @T.Pasichnyk that doesn't change the problem though. The video should be at the same frame as the thumbnail, but it's not. So you can see the bottom of the thumbnail and above it is the video

Comment: is thumbnail the same size as video frames?

Comment: @T.Pasichnyk no, they seem to be different sizes and I don't get why

Comment: then you should first figure this one out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be rather simple. Basically each post contains either post or a video, but either way, it always contains an image. I also set the `ratio` of that image (the `width` devided by the `height`). So, all I had to do is set the player's `width` to the screen width devided by the ratio and it gives your the proper frame.

```
playerLayer.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / postRatio
```